# Facebook email Permission, OAuth2, doesnt work?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

since the new Auth Dialog from Facebook (for my App & homepage), I cannot get the dialog to show that my homepage/app needs the users email when connection to my homepage/app.

In the Auth-section of my app I've added "email" to the User & Friend Permissions. Also I've added it to the referal when someone clicks the "Login with facebook"-button.

When someone clicks the Facebook-button, he/she redirects to a page which has the PHP-code with Facebook SDK PHP (latest). Here's how I generate the send-to-url for the dialog:

```
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'email,publish_stream'));
header("Location: ".$login_url);
```

But when the Dialog pops up, the only permission request it does is "basic information". I need to request the Email. Am I stupid or is it a bug somehow? I've also recreated the App.

Comment: I've the exactly same problem. I ask for "email" permission, in "Preview Auth Dialog" I see this, but in "real world", users dont see this permission request, only "Basic Information"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There in no `req_perms` parameter anymore, it's called `scope` in OAuth2.

Read documentation for [`getLoginUrl`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/) to see correct parameters.

Answer (score 0):

in new dialog there are 2 kind of permissions normal permissions & extended permissions 
you should install app with normal permissions at first then page will redirect automatically
for extended permissions